# Dynamic addition of details in sql from PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I was coding a script for the following model:

Suppose there are 5 events. For the users to register for the events, they need to input some details. Registration is in the form of a team, but the number of members in each event are different.

In my sql table `events` there is a row `members` which stores the number of members for all the 5 events.

Using the data stored in the `members` row, I can run a `for-loop` for the HTML display of table, where the user can input his and his team details.

But I'm confused as to how I will code the `php` part? I know php, getting the information and storing them in the sql database, but in this particular case do I have to code separate `php` script for all the events as the number of members will not be the same.

**EDIT#1**

The events are for example. :

```
**event1**: number of members: 5 (mem_1, mem_2, mem_3, mem_4, mem_5) 
**event2**: number of members: 3 (mem_1, mem_2, mem_3)
**event3**: number of members: 2 (mem_1, mem_2)
**event4**: number of members: 4 (mem_1, mem_2, mem_3, mem_4)
**event5**: number of members: 6 (mem_1, mem_2, mem_3, mem_4, mem_5, mem_6)
```

The `mem_x` fields store the name of the member.

So how can I code a single php script for the registration. Do I have to make separate functions for all the events as the number of members are different for the events.

Comment: it's not really clear.. can you explain better what do you want to achieve? If you need to insert an unknown number of rows in your database you could just do a for loop of queries.

Comment: @CosLu: Please see my edited question. Yes, I want to insert unknown number of rows.

Answer (score 1):

You check the inputted data to make sure that the number of members entered matches the number of members allowed for the event.

Then you loop over the data adding each (new) member to your members table, and the member_id and event_id to your members_events [junction table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table) (adding a number of rows equal to the number of members).

Answer (score 0):

If it were me, I'd have my table with the following fields:

```
Column Name        Example Value
member_id          [auto increment]
member_group       Step1
member_type        text
member_order       1
member_title       First Name
member_field_name  fname
member_default     enter first name
member_max_length  25
```

Then, in PHP, you can do a query like:

```
$fields = mysql_query("Select * From [member table] Where member_group = 'Step1' Order By member_order;")
while ($field = mysql_fetch_assoc($fields)) {?>
    <label for="<?= $field['member_field_name']; ?>">
       <?= $field['member_title']; ?>
       <? switch ($field['member_type']) {
           case "text":
               echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"".$field['member_field_name']."\" value=\"".$field['member_default']."\" />";
               break;
       }?>
    </label>
<?}
```

Then, when processing the page, just get the list of fields again from the database (for the field name) and process the page.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need different functions depending on the number of members.
You could for example store all the inserted members in an array and then do something like

```
foreach($members as $member){
   mysql_query ( "INSERT INTO members (name,eventID) VALUES (".$member['name'].",".$members['eventID'].")" );
}
```

where $members is the array containing the members names.

Is this what you wanted to know?